# SQLZOO Q#14 ORDER BY CASE Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to solve question number 14 (https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/AdventureWorks_hard_questions) in a particular way but I am having some issues with entries not appearing in any range. I just wanted to know if someone could point out out any problems with my approach.

EDIT: So from what what I have read the "BETWEEN" does not seem to capture decimal values and it is better to use <> operators. I will try this and get back here with my results. My issue as well is that there are no answers to these SQLZoo problems and a number of peoples submissions have varying results for this question.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty BETWEEN 0 AND 99 THEN '0 - 99'
        WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty BETWEEN 100 AND 999 THEN '100 - 999'
        WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty BETWEEN 1000 AND 9999 THEN '100 - 9999'
        WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty >= 10000 THEN '10000+'
        ELSE 'ERROR'
    END Range,
    COUNT(*) AS '# of Orders',
    SUM(ListPrice*SOD.OrderQty) AS 'Total Value'
FROM Product P
JOIN SalesOrderDetail SOD
ON P.ProductID = SOD.ProductID
GROUP BY            
CASE 
    WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty BETWEEN 0 AND 99 THEN '0 - 99'
    WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty BETWEEN 100 AND 999 THEN '100 - 999'
    WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty BETWEEN 1000 AND 9999 THEN '100 - 9999'
    WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty >= 10000 THEN '10000+'
    ELSE 'ERROR'
END
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use single quotes for identifiers such as column aliases. Yes, sadly SQL Server accepts that, but in SQL single quotes are usually for string (or date...) literals. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future SQL Server versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an error. Use square brackets for identifiers that have special characters in them or are case sensitive or preferably don't use special characters and case sensitive identifiers at all. Identifiers don't need to be "pretty", "pretty" headers and such are a job for the presentation layer.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites or just refer to them by words), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the recommendations in the comments under your post, I am referencing the question available here [SQLZOO #14](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/AdventureWorks_hard_questions).

You are seeing `ERROR` because your case statement doesn't capture the decimal values as shown below eg `99.98`.

***debug query***

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty BETWEEN 0 AND 99 THEN '0 - 99'
        WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty BETWEEN 100 AND 999 THEN '100 - 999'
        WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty BETWEEN 1000 AND 9999 THEN '100 - 9999'
        WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty >= 10000 THEN '10000+'
        ELSE 'ERROR'
    END Range,
ListPrice*OrderQty as Value,
    ListPrice,
    OrderQty

FROM Product P
JOIN SalesOrderDetail SOD
ON P.ProductID = SOD.ProductID
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

| Range | Value | ListPrice | OrderQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ERROR | 99.98 | 49.99 | 2 |
| ERROR | 99.98 | 49.99 | 2 |
| ERROR | 999.16 | 249.79 | 4 |
| ERROR | 99.98 | 49.99 | 2 |
| ERROR | 99.98 | 49.99 | 2 |
| ERROR | 99.98 | 49.99 | 2 |
| 10000+ | 16064.93 | 2294.99 | 7 |

You could try a more inclusive condition using `<` or `>` or boundaries with decimal places as shown below

```sql
CASE 
        WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty BETWEEN 0 AND 99.99 THEN '0 - 99'
        WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty BETWEEN 100 AND 999.99 THEN '100 - 999'
        WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty BETWEEN 1000 AND 9999.99 THEN '100 - 9999'
        WHEN ListPrice*OrderQty >= 10000 THEN '10000+'
        ELSE 'ERROR'
    END
```

which yields the following:

| Range | # of Orders | Total Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 - 99 | 80 | 4556.64 |
| 100 - 999 | 202 | 75724.01 |
| 100 - 9999 | 197 | 657811.89 |
| 10000+ | 21 | 365377.66 |

Comment: Or just don't use pesky `BETWEEN` but half open ranges with `>=` and `<`... Then it'll still work when the precision is increased and you won't have the same problem again.

Comment: @stickybit I did recommend that option in the answer as the more inclusive approach. Would you recommend that I modify my answer to not only mention the `<` and `>` but also include a full sql example ?

Comment: Well, it would emphasize it a little more...

Comment: @stickybit Thanks for the recommendation, however I'm seeing that the question is now closed.